# How to create equality test case for custom structures in julia

Tags: testing, julia, equality

I have created a struct

```
mutable struct mystruct
    x::Float64
    i::Int
end
```

Now when I initialize it using function x_init:

```
function x_init(x::Number,i::Int)::mystruct
    x = float(x)
    Z = mystruct(x,i)
    return Z
end
```

On running this function I get

```
julia> x_init(2,3)
mystruct(2.0, 3)
```

But on testing `@test x_init(2,3) == mystruct(2.0, 3)` I get `false`.

I expected to get `true`.

Could someone please explain why I got `false` and how I should write a test-case for such functions?

I can test like

```
x_init(2,3).x == mystruct(2.0, 3).x && x_init(2,3).i == mystruct(2.0, 3).i
```

but is there a better method which does not involve checking each variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`==` (`Base.:==`) is the generic equality operator that you can overload. If you don't overload `==`, it falls back to `===` (`Core.:===`), which you can't overload. `===` compares *immutable* objects by value, but it compares *mutable* objects by memory address. Although `x_init(2,3)` and `mystruct(2.0, 3)` have the same value, those are separate instances of `mutable mystruct` and thus have different memory addresses.

This overload will make `x_init(2,3) == mystruct(2.0, 3)` return `true`:

```
Base.:(==)(a::mystruct, b::mystruct) = a.x===b.x && a.i===b.i
```

P.S. the `::mystruct` annotation in your `x_init` method header is unnecessary. Return type annotations possibly add a `convert` step upon return, but the compiler can infer the return type of `x_init` must be `mystruct` and will omit the `convert` step.